Как на удаленном РС оставить курсор в отсутствии пользователя?
Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой, что в отсутствии пользователя на удаленном рабочем столе (вход через RDP, сессию не заканчиваю, машина виртуальная) курсор исчезает из-за чего не срабатывают скрипты на Python. Такое же происходит, если увезти курсор из окна удаленного РС в любое другое на физической машине.
Для эмуляции движений курсора пробовал различные библиотеки типа mouse, pyautogui - не работают, так как курсор висит в позиции 0:0 и не планирует двигаться. Возможно, есть какая-то эмуляция подключения мыши, чтобы курсор всегда был видимой области окна удаленного РС?
На подобные вопросы гугл не дает советов, все выдаваемые запросы об исчезновении курсора на удаленных РС.
Надеюсь, понятно объяснил проблему.

В отсутствии пользователя  включается режим блокировки экрана, а в нём инпуты мыши/Клавы не работают. Что-то в фоне крутить ещё можно, даже что-то из программ запускать, но ввод будет блокировать сама винда. Единственное что может сработать это ввод через hwnd если нужный софт умеет обрабатывать нажатия посланные в окно через postmessage.. что собственно автоматизируете?

@Amgarak есть десктопная программа, которую нерадивые девопсы дали мне на тестирование, а АПИ не вывели для тестов. Приходится автоматизацию тестирования делать скриптами с использованием мыши, клавиатуры. Что-то вроде узкопрофильного проприетарного Notepad++

Максимум что можете потестить тогда это посылать в окно команды или не выходить из рдп‍♀️

@Amgarak , а может подскажите, нет ли такой загвоздки на Астре Линукс? Если схожее пробовать на ней есть ли там блокировка экрана или может быть это более гибко настраивается там?

Не подскажу, не тестировал на линуксах такого рода автоматизации. Но подозреваю что результат будет тем же.

Чтобы оставить курсор активным на удаленном компьютере при отсутствии пользователя с использованием Python, можно использовать несколько подходов. Однако следует учитывать, что управление курсором и взаимодействие с графическим интерфейсом отдаленного компьютера может быть не всегда тривиальной задачей и зависит от операционной системы и используемых библиотек.
Вот несколько подходов, которые могут помочь в решении данной задачи.
1. Использование библиотеки pyautogui
Библиотека pyautogui позволяет управлять курсором мыши и выполнять различные действия в графическом интерфейсе. Чтобы курсор оставался активным, вы можете периодически перемещать его на небольшие расстояния.
Установка библиотеки
Если у вас еще не установлена библиотека pyautogui, вы можете установить её с помощью pip:
pip install pyautogui

Пример кода
import pyautogui
import time

# Периодическое движение курсора
def keep_cursor_active():
    while True:
        # Получаем текущие координаты курсора
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        # Перемещаем курсор на 1 пиксель вправо и обратно
        pyautogui.moveTo(x + 1, y)
        time.sleep(5)  # Ждем 5 секунд
        pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)  # Возвращаем курсор на место
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    keep_cursor_active()

2. Использование библиотеки ctypes для Windows
Если вы работаете на Windows, можно использовать библиотеку ctypes для взаимодействия с API Windows и перемещения курсора.
Пример кода
import ctypes
import time

# Определяем структуру POINT
class POINT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", ctypes.c_int), ("y", ctypes.c_int)]

# Функция для получения текущей позиции курсора
def get_cursor_position():
    pt = POINT()
    ctypes.windll.user32.GetCursorPos(ctypes.byref(pt))
    return pt.x, pt.y

# Функция для перемещения курсора
def set_cursor_position(x, y):
    ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(x, y)

def keep_cursor_active():
    while True:
        x, y = get_cursor_position()
        # Перемещаем курсор на 1 пиксель вправо и обратно
        set_cursor_position(x + 1, y)
        time.sleep(5)  # Ждем 5 секунд
        set_cursor_position(x, y)  # Возвращаем курсор на место
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    keep_cursor_active()

3. Использование pywinauto
Если вы работаете с приложениями Windows, библиотека pywinauto может помочь вам в управлении окнами и курсором.
Установка библиотеки
pip install pywinauto

Пример кода
from pywinauto import Application
import time

app = Application().connect(path='your_application.exe')  # Замените на путь к вашему приложению
window = app.window(title='your_window_title')  # Замените на заголовок окна приложения

def keep_cursor_active():
    while True:
        # Перемещаем курсор на 1 пиксель вправо и обратно
        window.set_focus()  # Сначала фокусируем окно
        window.move_mouse_input()
        time.sleep(5)  # Ждем 5 секунд
        window.move_mouse_input()
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    keep_cursor_active()

Примечания

Безопасность: Убедитесь, что использование таких методов не нарушает политику безопасности вашей сети или компьютера. Некоторые антивирусные программы могут блокировать автоматические действия.
Зависимости: Убедитесь, что все необходимые библиотеки установлены на удаленном компьютере, если вы запускаете скрипт на нем.
Права администратора: В некоторых случаях для управления курсором могут потребоваться права администратора, особенно на Windows.

Заключение
Выбор метода зависит от ваших нужд и окружения (Windows, Linux и т.д.). Убедитесь, что используете подходящий метод для вашей операционной системы и соблюдаете все правила безопасности.

вы за последний час написали три ответа разной тематики размером с небольшое эссе. есть основания полагать, что эти ответы вы написали не самостоятельно. хочу напомнить, что использования ChatGPT и других подобных ресурсов для написания ответов на этом сайте крайне не приветствуется.

@Matvj, проверяйте, пожалуйста, то, что вы копируете из ответов ИИ, вы не вникли в суть ответа и просто сюда выложили. А я с самого начала написал, что пользовался библиотеками, в том числе той, о которой вы пишите.
